# Windows vs Linux for server side script for .NET licensing system?

Tags: php, .net, licensing, activation

I was just wondering if there is a licensing system (free or commercial) for a `.NET` program that uses PHP instead of `ASP.NET` for the server side of the licensing system.
I have looked at pretty much all of them (`InstallKey`, `Activatar`, `SoftwareKey`, `CryptoLicensing`, etc) and they all need a Windows server to run.
I personally don't like `Windows` servers because of their stability and would much rather use a `Linux` server instead.

My other question is if there is a reason they uses `WCF/ASP.NET` and how easy it is to convert `ASP.NET` to `PHP`?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It wouldn't be difficult creating your own simple licensing system with .Net and PHP.

I use C# when programming and for licensing I use short polling (or long polling depending on what the program is) to connect to the server. You could easily create a WebRequest on the application startup to POST to the server for the licensing status of the user. It would save you a lot of money.